# Livecode: script in the code editor is not color-coded

Tags: livecode

My script in the code editor is not color-coded. Only terms like "put" or "else" are shown in bold letters. Is this a problem in the settings? [I've made a screen capture showing the script editor with uncolorized syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9oFW.png)

Answer (score 0):

First check the colorization settings in the Preferences stack. Colorization may be set to none, default and Revolution Classic.

You may try re-installing LiveCode. Removing the preferences stack may also help (from the LiveCode settings folder, not from the IDE folder).

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu Edit/Preferences on the main bar, you will see preferences stack then click on "Reset all preferences to default" button.